# What is cfinteractive process in Yocto?

Tags: camera

I am facing a problem with my Camera image fetching program stop working. When the program has no response, I captured the following info by `ps` command:
[image]

What is the first process `cfinteractive`?

Comment: I am in the same boat I am running LUbuntU on OrangePi and seeing cfintercative always on top:

Answer (score 1):

`cfinteractive` is a kernel thread for the *Interactive* governor of the CPUFreq driver.  You can verify that your system is using this governor with:

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

And you can temporarily disable CPU frequency scaling with the command:

`echo performance > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

You need to do that for each of your CPUs.